# Wordpress random post code only show post from one author

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a piece of code to show a random post under a post. But this code only show me the post's write from the author of that post.
Whats wrong?

```
    <?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=3'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <article>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('photo-thumbnail') ?></a>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                            <h3 style="font-weight:bold; margin-top: 0px; line-height: 1.3;"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnailFooter">
                <div class="pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?></div>
                <div class="smallFont pull-left" style="margin-left: 5px; width: 240px;"><span class="blue bold"><?php the_author(); ?></span></div>
                <div class="verySmallFont pull-left" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -3px;">en <span class="bold gray"><?php the_category(none); ?></span> el <?php the_time('j F, Y'); ?> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I believe it's because of your global_query it has initially selected the author and it picks up a random post of THAT author. So I would reset the query for the part where you want the random post/article and create new query,.

Comment: How can I reset the query? :)

Comment: I used  <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>  after the loop endif but not works

Answer (score 0):

I'll ask again my answer with more data on other post

[Can't reset query to show ramdom post after firs loop Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066559/cant-reset-query-to-show-ramdom-post-after-firs-loop-wordpress)