# Can't reset query to show ramdom post after firs loop Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a piece of code to show a random post under a post. But this code only show me the post's write from the author of that post. Whats wrong?

```
    <!-- post -->
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

        <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>
        <?php the_author(); ?>
        <?php the_category(none); ?>
        <?php the_date(); ?>


        <?php the_content();?>
        <?php $key="video"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
        <?php $key="imagen"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- ramdom post -->

    <?php $posts = $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=3'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
       <?php the_post_thumbnail('photo-thumbnail') ?>
        <?php the_author(); ?>
        <?php the_category(none); ?>


    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after the first query.

Comment: I tried that after  <?php endwhile; ?> , <?php else : ?> and <?php endif; ?> and not works :(

Comment: Your '<?php else : ?>' doesn't have a function, you should remove that. The correct place for the reset query would be after the endif. The rest of your code looks fine, I would't know why it's not working properly.

Comment: I removed  '<?php else : ?>'  and add <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> after endif and not works :(

Comment: This is the web, maybe can help http://lavozdelmuro.com/quien-decia-que-las-mujeres-que-ocupaban-altos-cargos-no-llevaban-una-vida-familiar/

Comment: what if you replace 'get_posts' by 'query_posts' in the 2nd loop?

Comment: If I use query_posts appears a lot of post of that user, but not of ramdom users

Answer (score 0):

Replace the random post code with the code below. In your example you were querying 3 posts. If that's not your intention and you only want a single post replace 3 with 1 in posts_per_page.

```
$secondary_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'no_found_rows' => 1, ) );
if ( $secondary_posts->have_posts() ) : while ( secondary_posts->have_posts() ) : $secondary_posts->the_post();

the_post_thumbnail( 'photo-thumbnail' );
the_author();
the_category();

endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Something in my sintax is not correct (i'm a beginner) the pages don't load. This is the code of the ramdom post with your changes. http://jsfiddle.net/9mu54/

Comment: I took a look at the jsfiddle. You haven't wrapped endwhile or endif in PHP tags. Add those in and it should work fine. Make sure wp_reset_postdata is in PHP tags as well. Also you're missing a semi-colon after the_post_thumbnail function. It shouldn't be an issue but worth tidying it up. If you're still having an issue turn on error reporting.

Comment: I did that but show a white page -> (ramdom code part) http://jsfiddle.net/9mu54/1/ (entire page code) --> http://jsfiddle.net/9Z9vP/

Comment: That may be my fault actually. I have just edited my answer. You need to add parenthesis around the have_posts method inside if. So if ( $secondary_posts->have_posts() ) : ...